# how to restrict manual creation of tags in CKAN

Tags: jquery-select2, ckan

how to restrict manual creation of tags in CKAN. currently user can search existing tags and also add a new tag.

Comment: for select2 you can do --> tags: false <-- not sure ckan

Comment: @DanielH Thanks. yes, it works for select2 but in CKAN they have overriden it by enforcing tags: true. i had to comment out createSearchChoice function to partially achieve what i wanted